# Excel DSum function multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: dsum]

Hello guys, I have been trying to implement the `DSUM` function but failed to figure it out. I looked through the previous `DSUM` posts on here and still don't understand. This is my problem:

1. on I8:L9, i have to implement the `DSUM` to calculate the "calculated quantity sold" for each item, ie Textbook, Novel,notepad and laptop. from A9-A16
2. I am supposed to use these values on B20 - B23. I don't know how to make sure i have multiple criteria for the `DSUM` function.
3. I tried this and it worked only for the first function: =DSUM(bookstore,J8,I8:I9)
4. This gave me the correct value only for Textbook, It summed up the quantities for textbook. What I want to do now is replicate it down so that it is the same for all the other elements.

Please help. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the setup you have then using this formula in B20 copied down will give the **cumulative total** of the categories

`=DSUM(Bookstore,J$8,I$8:I9)`

so that will give the sum for **Textbook** only in B20 but then in B21 it will be the sum for **Textbook** and **Novel** combined....then in B22 **Textbook**, **Novel** and **Notepad** (A22 should be "Notepad" to match I11)

To get the sum for the item in question only you could subtract the previous values above, i.e. use this version in B20 copied down

`=DSUM(Bookstore,J$8,I$8:I9)-SUM(B$19:B19)`

....but all things being equal I agree with user667489, except `SUMIF` is usually preferable for a single condition, i.e. in B20 copied down

`=SUMIF(A$9:A$16,A20,D$9:D$16)`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason that you need to use DSUM to do this? You're making life very hard for yourself. You could do this much more easily via SUMPRODUCT or by using a pivot table.

When you create a column of conditions on the same variable, and you specify that as your constraint range for DSUM, excel sums over your database range where **any** of those conditions are true. You can't make it apply the constraint from just one row, unless that's the only row other than the column headings. So you need to put your different constraints for the same variable in different columns. This gets very messy.

Here is a sumproduct formula that will accomplish what you're trying to do, which can be copied down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$9:$D$16)*($A$9:$A$16=I9))
```

Paste that into cells J9:J12 (or B20:B23).

Comment: Its because the question says i must use DSum to add the quantities for each category, like for all the textbooks, laptops, novels and notepads. So instead of having 4 criterias i thought maybe  i could just drag down the formula

Comment: I'm fairly sure that there is no simple way of producing a DSUM-only formula that you can drag down from the top cell. @Barry's answer is probably as close as you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative having entered the DSUM formula in B20 is to select the range B20:B23 and choose *Data > What If Analysis > Data Table... Column Input Cell: I9, OK*. This should give the formulas below:

```
B20:      =DSUM(bookstore,J8,I8:I9)
B21:B23: {=TABLE(,I9)}
```

**Note**: the Table formula cannot be entered from the formula bar, it is automatically generated by the Data Table command. (The same procedure could also be used to enter formulas in J9 and J10:13.)

I'd also recommend using `SUMIF`, or looking at PivotTables which could be used easily for this and create the list of categories for you.